# can dpkg obtain the source code of a package?

Tags: apt, software-center, dpkg, deb, source-code

`apt-get source {some-package-name}`
gets the source code of that .deb.

Can this be achieved with `dpkg` instead? Or with software-center?

Answer (score 2):

No, dpkg is strictly a local command acting on downloaded packages (by apt-get). Software Center on the other hand is a high level GUI that desperately hides such functionality from the user.